# Length of array saved in entry 0?

Tags: php

i read information out of a MSSQL database and save this into arrays with a length of 2000.
When i echo the entries i get the length of these arrays in the first entry (e.g. amount[0] = 2000).

Does php do this by default or is there no default value?

(The cells in my database which go into these arrays are empty in the first entry)

Thank You

Comment: when i declared the array i gave them 2000 entries, now this value is stored in the first entry of the array

Comment: _“Does php do this by default ”_ - no, it doesn’t do this _at all_. _Your_ code (or whatever lib/framework you are using) must be doing this.

Comment: Without code we can only speculate what you are doing.

Comment: ok, thank you, this is what i wanted to know (@misorude)

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your question very well. PHP uses a function called count() to determine the length of an array ,you can do somethiing like this,
$x = [12,11,334,56,788,999,45,56,23];
$y = count($x);
then change the value of the first array element like this,
$x[0] = $y;
So whenever you call $x[0] you will get the length of the array.

Comment: _“PHP uses a function called strlen() to determine the length of an array”_ - no, it doesn’t. strlen gets the length of a string; to get the number of elements inside an array `count` should be used. What you are suggesting would issue a _“Warning:  strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given”_, and result in $y being NULL.

Comment: Yes you are right, my mistake.I was referring to the count() function.Thanks for the heads -up.